# Applying Custom Blur Effect with Color Overlay in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on enhancing the visual appeal of my React Native app and would like to implement a specific blur effect. I would like to apply a blur effect that covers the top and bottom portions of the screen with a custom color overlay.

Could you guide me on how to create a blur effect on the top and bottom edges of the screen and also add a color overlay on the blurred areas? Are there any specific libraries or techniques in React Native that I should use? Additionally, how can I control the intensity and color of the blur to match my design specifications?

Thank you for your assistance!

[Image as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEqug.png)

I expected the top and bottom of my screen to have a blur effect, with the designated area showing through a colored tint that I applied as an overlay.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.